# How to prevent mails from being marked spam while sending through Rails4 using Amazon SES

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, email-spam

I am developing an application to send mails using Amazon SES service. I have verified my gmail account and have been able to send mails to gmail accounts, some yahoo mail ids and a few another domains without being marked as spam. However, when I send it to windows live account it is marked as spam. I even tried verifying my hotmail account and sending to the same using AWS::SES.

Can someone please suggest a way to guarantee a good delivery for my mails?

Thanks,
Ranjani

Comment: This has not really much to do with the technological aspect. Spam filters normally decide if they put something in spam based on content and sender. Maybe this helps: http://www.seas.upenn.edu/cets/answers/spamblock-filter.html

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It goes to spam even when I tried changing to the subject and content according to the way suggested in the link. I guess sending from AWS-SES is the reason ? Can my assumption be right?

Comment: yes, quite possible. Those large mailers can be easily used for spam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting your mails out of spam filters is not easy. 
Technically these two are important:
1. Setup SPF 
2. Setup DKIM

Then the third is the language you use in the emails.
Another is your email provider's reputation.

This has more info:
How to Avoid Spam Filters | MailChimp : http://mailchimp.com/resources/guides/how-to-avoid-spam-filters/